# POST Json web API C#

Tags: c#, httpclient, rest

I am trying post `api` through `HTTP` client in `C#`, For authorization ,we send `Bearer` token.
But it is not getting inserted in the client side. It throws an error.

My code here:

```cs
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            string result = "";
            using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", "ebpPermHash=-396055074);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authtoken);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
                
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/v2/bb/sa", payModel).Result;
                
                var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = responseString.Result;
                dynamic data = JObject.Parse(result);
                string throwresult = Convert.ToString(data);
                result = data.authToken;
                logErr.ControlLog(throwresult);
            }
            return result;
```

But I am getting error like:

```json
exceptionType": "com.ebpsource.exception.AuthenticationFailedException",
  "name": "AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED",
  "message": "Authentication is required to call 'Resource.execute'",
  "address": "/service/Resource.execute",
  "httpRequestBody": {
    "header": {
      "config": {
        "action": "insert",
        "resourceName": "sa"
      }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check your backend with Postman first, to verify if it is a backend issue or a client issue

Comment: Hi, I tried with postman no issues in that, but in c# code i try to implement it. but throws an error like ```` Id = 72, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "{\"exceptionType\":\"com.ebpsource.exception.AuthenticationFailedException\",\"name\":\"AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED\",
\"message\":\"Authentication is required to call 'Resource.execute'\",\"address\":\"/service/Resource.execute\",\"httpRequestBody\":{\"header\":{\"config\":{\"action\":\"insert\",
\"resourceName\":\"sa\"}}````.

Comment: please try to convert the postman request to c# code from the postman, please check https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

you have a bug, a wrong syntax to add a token. And plus to many headers. Try this

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);        
var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");  
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payModel);
var contentData = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response =  client.PostAsync("/v2/bb/sa", contentData).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
var stringData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(stringData);
}
}
```

UPDATE

if you need to add cookies you can do it this way

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    ....
    cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("CookieName", "cookie_value"));
.....
}
```

Comment: Hi Serge, I tried with your code, it throws me the error  ````{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, 
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,DELETE,PUT,POST
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,Action,cache-control,if-modified-since,pragma,ebpAppKey
  Date: Fri, 20 Aug 2021 12:54:45 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}````

Comment: @padmapriya I am sorry but I  think that your token is not valid for this APi or  token role is not allowed. Can you post an API and startup file of API pls?

Comment: Hi Serge,  the problem is regarding setting up cookie. I have two cookies example: ebpPermHash, ebpauth. I need to assign value for these two cookies in my code. Can you share how to add these cookies with bearer authorization.

Comment: Ok I didn't know that you are using cookies for authorization. Try to add them.

Comment: Hi Serge, this is code to generate token ```` HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/v2/bb/authtoken", authToken).Result; var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();result = responseString.Result;dynamic data = JObject.Parse(result); cookies = (header => header.Key == "Set-Cookie").Value;sring throwresult = Convert.ToString(data);result data.authToken;l;````                          I use this authtoken and generate two cookies ebpPermHash; ebpauth;.Now i am passing  only authtoken in post api .i need to pass cookies too. How could i pass ? do you have an idea ?

Comment: @padmapriya pls check my answer